# Swift UITableView: How to collect the data from selected cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I would like to know how to collect data from previous page when using UITableView.

It's hard to explain so I will give you an example.

Apple default calendar app has this feature in the New Event Page.
When you open the New Even page, you will see Never in Repeat field. To change this, you need to tap Never and go to the next page and select something like Every Week. If you select Every Week, it will go back to the first page and the Repeat field now shows Weekly.

I would like to make something similar but not sure how to set this up... My questions are; Do I need to use Segue? Do I need to use UITextField or UILabel for the cell? What triggers to pass the data?

Comment: Welcome in stackoverflow, you post tried code so we can help with you problem

Comment: Generally speaking you are asking for passing data between view controllers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

MainviewController to add Below code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // "SelectionSegue" is same as storyboard segue identifier
    if segue.identifier == "SelectionSegue" {
        (segue.destination as! SelectCategoryViewController).selectedCategoryValue = self.selectedCategoryLabel.text!
        print(selectedCategoryLabel)
    }
}
```

Set Segue Identifier in Storyboard

[image]

SelectedTableView

```
var selectedCategoryValue:String = ""
var CategeryArray = ["Food","Travel","Shopping","Card","MyReserve","Game","Songs","Movies","Entertainment","Business","Education","Finance","Drink","Sports","Social","Lifestyle"]
```

//Add TableView Delegate and Data Source Methods

```
extension SelectCategoryViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return CategeryArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.CategeryArray[indexPath.row]

        if self.CategeryArray[indexPath.row] == self.selectedCategoryValue {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        } 

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        self.selectedCategoryValue = CategeryArray[indexPath.row]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

My View Like

[image]

NavigationController -> Mainview -> SelectedTableView

Comment: you don't think `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark` is unnecessary in `didSelectRowAt` method?

Comment: Thanks Ramprasathselvam! Can you let me know where did you declare "selectedCategoryLabel"?

Comment: MainViewController "None" Text is selectCategoryLabel @Riki_U

Comment: Thanks Ramprasathselvam! So do I add it as Identifier in the storyboard? Or shall I declare as variable?

Comment: You can add Identifier in storyboard @Riki_U